# Loading Loughran finance sentiment into Tidytext

Tags: tidytext

I'm using the sentiment tools in Tidytext for the first time, and would like to use the Loughran dictionary.  After several attempts, the closest I get is this error:

> get_sentiments("loughran")
>   Error in get_sentiments("loughran") : could not find function "%>%"

Is Loughran a Tidytext offering or must it be externally retrieved/loaded? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Loughran sentiment lexicon is in the version of tidytext that is on GitHub but not yet on CRAN. We will be releasing a new version on CRAN in the near future! In the meantime, you can install the current development version of tidytext from GitHub using devtools:

```r
library(devtools)
install_github("juliasilge/tidytext")


library(tidytext)
get_sentiments("loughran")
#> # A tibble: 4,149 × 2
#>            word sentiment
#>           <chr>     <chr>
#> 1       abandon  negative
#> 2     abandoned  negative
#> 3    abandoning  negative
#> 4   abandonment  negative
#> 5  abandonments  negative
#> 6      abandons  negative
#> 7     abdicated  negative
#> 8     abdicates  negative
#> 9    abdicating  negative
#> 10   abdication  negative
#> # ... with 4,139 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm sorry my up-vote doesn't count, I'm new here.